# how to make track user location while going in destination in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationlistener, real-time-updates

Friend I want to make an app which show the user **location or track** the user location **Real Time**.
like as shown in figure 
we just want to track the user until reached in destination.
[while user follows in route for destination.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zck5b.jpg)
Thanks *Ahsan Saeed*.

Comment: What you tried so far ??

Comment: yes i am done.. i am getting location (Start to end point) but when i start walking my map did not update or did not show the new Longitude and Latuitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a location change listener as shownl in this link [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

also if you are able to get the `lastKnownLocation()`, then you can simply use a timer to get the location after specified time

```
void getUpdate(){
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
        //Get last known location here 
               getLastKnownLocation();
        //update the map's marker with the new LatLng

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 5 seconds
        }
}
```

Comment: According to our code, the map will change or update every 5 seconds right?

Comment: correct. So you will be getting the `lastKnownLocation()` every five seconds. Then you can map the marker using the value.